# Is there a package for an executable version of v8?

Tags: 12.04, package-management, javascript

I'm trying to get [Vim JS lint plugin](https://github.com/joestelmach/lint.vim) working under Ubuntu 12.04. The plugin requires the  `d8` command, which is an executable version of [Google's v8 JavaScript Engine](http://code.google.com/p/v8/).

I do see a [libv8](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libv8-3.7.12.22) package, but that doesn't seem to either install `d8` or at least, not put it on my path. The package is described as

> libv8-3.7.12.22 - v8 JavaScript engine - runtime library

**Is there any package that will install an executable version of the v8 engine, or do I just have to build it manually?**

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802478/running-v8-javascript-engine-standalone.

Comment: @lazy1, I had seen that. I think d8 is the newer version of v8-shell. It gives an interactive shell that lets you run javascript commands.

Comment: If you follow the instructions at http://code.google.com/p/v8/wiki/BuildingWithGYP. And run "make native", you'll have a d8 executable at out/native which you can copy to someplace in path.

Comment: @lazy1, Yeah I compiled it and got it up and running shortly after creating the question. I prefer to do things through APT if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am going to take the lack of answers as a no.

It is not difficult to make and install v8 from Google's SVN repo.

All you need to do is check it out and make it.

```
svn checkout http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ ./v8
cd v8
make builddeps
make native
```

Then inside the `out/native` directory there will be `d8` binary, I just symlinked this to my `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: if you change `make dependencies` to `make builddeps`, you won't need to have `gclient` built and installed.

Comment: Is Answer still applicable? `svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk'`

Comment: The repository has been moved into GitHub: https://github.com/v8/v8

Comment: beware this takes gigabytes of download, disk space and hours of compiling.

Answer (score 1):

This might help (it works on Debian):

```
12:38 ~ $ apt-cache search libv8;
libv8-3.8.9.20 - v8 JavaScript engine - runtime library
libv8-dbg - v8 JavaScript engine - debugging symbols
libv8-dev - v8 JavaScript engine - development files
libv8-i18n-dev - Native internationalization extension for libv8 - development files
libv8-i18n0.0.0 - Native internationalization extension for libv8 - runtime library
libv8-i18n0.0.0-dbg - Native internationalization extension for libv8 - debugging symbols
```

and choose one such as

```
12:39 ~ $ apt-get install libv8-3.8.9.20
```

Comment: How to include it to a cpp script?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit), it works with major operating systems (Linux, Windows, Mac) - it's an app engine made from chromium and node.js.